# Prove that $(Y_{t})_{t\in[0,\epsilon]}$ is a martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, local-martingales

I am struggling the following exercise:

> Processes $X$ and $Y$ are defined as:
>   $$X=\Bigg( \int_{0}^{t}e^{W_{s}^{2}}\mathrm{d}W_{s}\Bigg)_{t\ge 0},$$
>   $$Y=\Bigg(\int_{0}^{t}W_{s}^{5}\mathrm{d}X_{s} \Bigg)_{t\ge 0}.$$
>   Prove that $\ (Y_{t})_{t\in[0,\epsilon]} \ $ is a martingale for some $\epsilon>0$.

As I understand, it is straight forward to check, that $X$ is a local martingale.
Thus, applying integration by substitution, we get
$$Y_{s}=\int_{0}^{t}W_{s}^{5}e^{W_{s}^{2}}\mathrm{d}W_{s}.$$
Just from construction of isometric integral, I see that $Y$ is a local martingale too. But I do not know how to handle it from here. Only one way I can see, would be proving that $Y$ is somehow bounded for some small $\epsilon$. But I am not so sure if that is really the case here.

Comment: **Hint:** Compute the $E[\exp(2W_s^2)]$. You will find that it is finite for $0\le s<s_0$, and then $X$ is a square-integrable martingale on the time interval $[0,\epsilon]$, for each $0<\epsilon<s_0$, by Ito's isometry.

Comment: Thank You, that is it.